# How to compare Dates from database in Yii2

Tags: yii2

```
$time = new \DateTime('now');
$today = $time->format('Y-m-d');
$programs=Programs::find()->where(['close_date' >= $today])->all();
```

This is code for today's programs whose `close_date` is greater than `today's date`. I am getting error:

> "Invalid Parameter -yii\base\InvalidParamException Operator '1'
>   requires two operands".

Comment: No need to build the date like this, you could use `new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to write `where` condition as array the code should be like this:

```
$programs = Programs::find()->where(['>=', 'close_date', $today])->all();
```

Check [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail) for more details:

> Additionally you can specify arbitrary operators as follows: A
>   condition of `['>=', 'id', 10]` will result in the following SQL
>   expression: `id >= 10`.

Answer (score 2):

Or like this code:

```
$programs = Programs::find()->where('close_date >= :close_date', [':close_date' => $today])->all();
```