# Yii2 query get where

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Am trying to perform a query and get items where created_at is not greater that 24 hrs

I have tried

```
$trucks = Orders::find()
         ->where(["created_at"=>not more than 24 hrs ]) //stuck here

                ->orderBy(['created_at' => SORT_DESC])->all();
```

Nb:Created_at is in unix timestamp.

in usual php it would be the equivalent of

```
    $created_at= 1500373706; // time order was created

    if ((time() - $created_at) > 86400) {
         //Dont get these
      } else {
         //Get these
     }
```

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer and made some very slight modifications to fit your situation: [How to compare Dates from database in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470160/how-to-compare-dates-from-database-in-yii2)

```
$yesterday = strtotime("-24 hours");
$trucks = Orders::find()->where(['<=', 'created_at', $yesterday])
    ->orderBy('created_at DESC')->all();
```

Comment: Great, I made that change.